# Cant boot HP PC completely after change of video card

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, bios, computer-building

I recently bought a new video card but after installing it in my HP PC, boot failed; it stays on the boot screen and the motherboard makes 1 short sound and then a long one.

pc specifications

- [Intel i3-2100](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/es/es/ark/products/53422/intel-core-i3-2100-processor-3m-cache-3-10-ghz.html)
- [HP Motherboard IPISB-CU (CARMEL2)](https://support.hp.com/hk-en/document/c02980014)
- This is the new Graphic card i'm trying to install [Gigabyte GTX 1050 Ti OC 4GB](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N105TOC-4GD-rev-10-rev11-rev12#kf)

The pc had a [GT 640 PNY](https://www.pny.com/File%20Library/Support/PNY%20Products/Resource%20Center/Graphics%20Cards/Spanish/Product%20Brochure/PNY-Verto-GT-640-1GB-SPA.pdf) before and worked without problems with 2 monitors

I already tried to remove other drivers, and reinstalling them

right now the PC still has the GT 640 and it works fine

Could this be a Motherboard or a CPU incompatibility issue with the graphic card?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be power related.  What's your PSU rating?  The beep code you mention suggests a memory problem, are you sure it's not 2 short and 1 long

Comment: i dont think that would be the issue, i have a EVGA 650W 80 gold
more about it, here: https://latam.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=210-GQ-0650-V1
as far as i know i think theres plenty room for the components i mentioned, and the pc only uses 1 SSD and 1 HDD

Comment: You are going from a GPU that requires 65 W to a GPU that requires 300 W.  I highly suspect this problem is due to your PSU not being up to the task.  A CPU cannot be incompatible with GPU like this, there is a small chance the problem is due to the motherboard only support PCIe 2.0, but I doubt that would prevent the system from successfully POSTing.  Since the PSU is the only thing you can upgrade on the system, I would do that, to rule that possibility out.

Comment: maybe that could be the reason becasue the graphic card doesnt have a 6 or a 8 pin conector, it depends of the energy that the pcie its giving to the card, i cant find any place to know about how may power can the gen 2 deliver to the card, in the end maybe a complete change of CPU, motherboard and RAM will be better because the system is really old, client says the pc is from 2011

Comment: @Ramhound i will consider this one as a valid answer for this question 
thanks for the help

Comment: @TamalesRancheros - I am not entirely sure what "the answer" was to be honest.  I only pointed out that the card now requires nearly 5x the power.  You made no mention of the fact the original card did or did not have a PCIe power connector in your question.

Comment: Did you check that your RAM is seated properly?  Maybe it got bumped or something.  As someone else mentioned, that code _should_ be a memory error.

Comment: @Ramhound i consider that comment about the energy of the pcie the answer

Comment: @JMac the ram wasnt the issue here, i didnt touch or removed the ram while doing the graphic card swap, as i mention before the pc is working fine with the old graphic card, im more inclined to think that the motherboard is the main issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching for solution i stumbled with this thread from HP
saying this:

> BIOS version 7.xx is a legacy BIOS.  Therefore you need a legacy graphics card. A NVIDIA GTX 660 would be about the best legacy graphics card. You might need a larger PSU such as a 500 watt model.

[HP forums](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Video-Display-and-Touch/Geforce-GT-1030-GTX-1050-Upgrade-1-beep-then-3-fast-beeps/td-p/6491389)

and also this

> Sandy Bridge platform, nope, [the platform lacks the necessary power](http://www.realhardtechx.com/index_archivos/Page362.htm) and the HP prebuilt unit will be limited to an incompatible BIOS environment. you would need to get something more concurrent like a Haswell platform if you'd like to drop in a GPU above the GTX600 series.
>
> If you want to work with what you have, you're yet going to have to change the PSU with more wattage+of a better quality and be able to drop in a GTX650.

[TomsHardware Forum](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/is-my-motherboard-compatible-with-my-graphics-card.2993042/)

So in summary the client requieres a whole upgrade of his PC in order for him to use that Graphics card.

Answer (score -1):

With the exception of a MAYBE needing a new power supply, the above post is wrong.

I've seen this A LOT, and many people think it's impossible to get a newer GPU installed due to the old BIOS (7.12) or older.  As long as the card fits, has PCIE 16, and your PSU can power it, most likely it will work.

IPISB-CU (Carmel2) and IPISB-CH2 (Chicago) ARE compatible with most GPUs, even newly released ones.  Read below.

These motherboard supports nearly any GPU from a firmware/hardwire and size perspective even a brand new 2022 May released 6650XT which is a 2.5 slot with 3 fans...though you will have to remove the upper ram plastic bracket hinges.  As you know, the problem is the UEFI version is very early and needs an update, so it's not compatible with any cards that don't offer legacy support. None of the BIOS versions make this fix. It looks like the RX 5xx series is the last known from AMD that offers this support, with one known exception--RX 5xx Sapphire cards don't work...without this fix anyway.

Here's the fix:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT9bb_0Fwbo
With this fix you need to enable integrated video, then set integrated video as primary. This in particular is quite annoying with HP, as they have blocked out the video ports in the back. They also state on the product support page that integrated video is "unavailable" with a discrete GPU, though I guess technically they're not wrong. Another strange thing is they use DVI rather than VGA. After taking off the plastic "blockers" then connecting a monitor to the integrated video and booting up the PC with new GPU, you can download the drivers and all of that to get it to run. After a reboot, everything works.